# Can you purge an apt package by stepping through the commands in the uninstall script, avoiding the failing commands?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, uninstall, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu on WSL, and a package I have installed fails when I am trying to run

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove elasticsearch
```

The particular package itself is not interesting here, but instead i wonder:

**Can you -somewhat conveniently - use some cli tool to step through the purge script one command at a time and then skip the failing steps?**

Comment: The [control information files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) for a package are placed in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` not sure there is any such tool but these files are usually not that complicated.

Comment: Not sure but in my experience it usually reports where it is failing, for example `preinst` or `postinst`. Then I edit those scripts to have them pass the step.

Comment: Rather than editing the script, if the error is a foolish one like "can't delete the file because it does not exist.", sometimes it is sufficient to just make an empty file with touch.